# Elasticsearch aggregation for dynamic attiribute

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

In ES, I need aggs for dynamic attribute fields.

My ES document structure

```
"_source": {
        "id": 80682,
                ....,
        "product_characters": [
            {
                "id": 128024,
                "value_id": 14194,
                "characters": {
                    "id": 749,
                    "slug": "rang",
                                        ...                 
                },
                "product_id": 80682,
                "character_id": 749
            },
                        ...
                 ]
}
```

There product document structure, and `product_characters` for attributes of product. And `value_id` for value of product, `character_id` for attribute type.

I need to get aggs of, all `character_id` types with count, and inside `value_id`'s count.

```
"aggs":[
    {
      "key":121,
      "count":3000,
      "value_id":[
          {
            "key":1402,
            "count":12,
          },
           ...
      ]

}
]
```

I have tried nested and filters, but not get disired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Terms Aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [Nested Aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) resolve your problem.

Ex:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_value": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "product_characters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_value_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_characters.value_id",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
         "agg_character_id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_characters.character_id",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```